# Why do the removal of some random alternative in this ANTLR grammar affects adaptive prediction in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, antlr4

I have a reduced grammar [here](https://gist.github.com/abyss7/5d51f7d40c8177bc3905451c2a65298c) (I'll try to reduce grammar even more while debugging an issue). I've tried to shrink it as much as I can. The problem can be reproduced on input:

> SELECT cast (a AS b)

followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for `EOF`.

I get an error:

> line 1:19 mismatched input ')' expecting AS

Using more verbose custom error listener shows that the parser tries to match the `columnExpr AS? identifier` alternative instead of `columnIdentifier` so that `AS` keyword can be parsed as part of `CAST` outer alternative.

And if I remove some grammar line i.e. `| showStmt` (alternative for `query`), the error is gone. I tried to trace the execution and it comes out that the difference is in the output of:

```
getInterpreter<atn::ParserATNSimulator>()->adaptivePredict(_input, <some number>, _ctx)
```

Also if the input is `SELECT cast (a AS b);` the error is gone too.

**Question**: is anything wrong with my grammar or should I just handle this error somehow and give the parser another try? I'm not familiar with different error-handling strategies and predictor modes, but maybe that's the issue.

---

The main.cpp file is simple:

```
#include "testLexer.h"
#include "testParser.h"

#include <CommonTokenStream.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace antlr4;

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;
    std::string query(begin, end);

    ANTLRInputStream input(query);
    testLexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    testParser parser(&tokens);

    parser.queryStmt();
}
```

The build line is simple too:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp test.g4 && clang++ -std=c++17 -g main.cpp testLexer.cpp testParser.cpp -I/usr/include/antlr4-runtime -lantlr4-runtime -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `EOF` in parser rules other than an entry point of your grammar, without any alternatives (!), can result in odd behavior. This might be the case with you.

Try something like this:

```
parse
 : queryStmt (EOF | SEMICOLON)
 ;

queryStmt
 : query
 | insertStmt
 ;
```

Testing this myself like this:

```java
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("SELECT cast (a AS b)"));
TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree root = parser.parse();
System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));
```

resulted in this (without any errors to my `stderr`):

```
(parse (queryStmt (query (selectUnionStmt (selectStmtWithParens (selectStmt SELECT (columnExprList (columnExpr cast ( (columnExpr (columnIdentifier (nestedIdentifier (identifier a)))) AS (identifier b) )))))))) <EOF>)
```

Comment: Actually `queryStmt` is the entry point, and another point is to not limit the `insertStmt` with `EOF` - there may go additional data parsed by another parser. Also, even if I remove EOF completely the issue still persists: like `(SEMICOLON)?`.

Comment: Not sure, but did you try exactly what I suggested? If so, you got the same error?

Comment: I used your suggestion about `EOF` usage outside of entry point and modified the rule `analyzeStmt` like `queryStmt` → `query`, and it works for now, but I have to make full tests on the whole grammar. Thanks! But anyway I still don't understand if this a bug or what.

Comment: Could be a bug in the C++ generator/runtime, I couldn't reproduce on Java and don't have C++ set up on my machine.